# Eclipse luna theme issue

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes, eclipse-luna

My Eclipse seems to have a problem with the themes. I use the standard dark theme that comes with it and I also use a color style to change the background/text color. I have the Luna version.

Even though it does accept the changes if I hit "Apply" and "OK" when I restart Eclipse it seems to ignore the changed color style. The same happens if I change the specific "Java Editor" settings...gone. I do NOT change workspaces or something like this... Any ideas are welcome, I can't stand the color pollution of the default theme. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try this (for me the problem was a collusion with c++ development plugin - but it should solve it):*

1. Help > Eclipse Marketplace > Search for "Eclipse Color Theme" and install "`Moonrise`".
2. Then go to: Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > and select the MoonRise theme
3. Then go to Appearance > Color Theme and select your theme

   - For themes to be available follow this: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin
   - **Note the difference** between `Color theme` and `Appearance Theme`

Answer (score 0):

The "default" and "Reduced palette" color and font themes have CSS warnings that don't seem to scale...![My eclipse running the Dark Theme][1] You could also use  [Jeeeyul's Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jeeeyuls-eclipse-themes)